# I have problem using ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging for pagination in my Asp.NET Core 2.2 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

The pagination is working fine for first page and it fetches results also.

But the problem is whenever I click on any page number in pagination (suppose I clicked 2), then it will search for Index.cshtml file instead of going to the method of that particular controller.

[image]

The below code is in the View of method `GetCustomers` which is inside `HomeController'. But it will search for`Index`method of`HomeController`

```
 <nav>
    @await this.Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.PagerViewComponent), new { pagingList = this.Model }))
 </nav>
```

What changes should I make in the code so that it will go to method `GetCustomers` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could set Action property to your PagingList object like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page = 1)
{
      var qry = _context.Customer.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(c => c.Name);
      var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(qry, 10, page);
      model.Action = "GetCustomers";
      return View(model);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed some code in your view ,

try changing it From

```
<nav>
@await this.Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.PagerViewComponent), 
new { pagingList = this.Model }))
</nav>
```

To

```
<nav aria-label="Suppliers navigation example">
@await this.Component.InvokeAsync("Pager", new { pagingList = this.Model })
</nav>
```

and add this at top of the your view

```
@model ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.PagingList<"Your Model">
@using ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging
@addTagHelper *, ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging
```

and add this in your controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page = 1) {
var qry = _context.Suppliers.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(p => p.CompanyName);
var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(qry, 10, page);
return View(model);
}
```

and for more details Refer this URL

https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2017/paging-in-asp-net-core-mvc-and-entityframework-core

Answer (score 0):

public async Task Index(int page = 1)

instead of page use pageIndex . it will be like that

public async Task Index(int pageIndex = 1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).